# Access windows device manager settings through script?

Tags: windows, drivers

We have a device that occasionally does not get mapped to the correct driver. It's a straightforward fix in device manager to correct this, but we'd rather not have end-users going through the steps to fix this. I am looking for some sort of script or something that can be done in an application or something that can fix how this driver is mapped so that end users don't have to go through advanced device manager settings.

I'm aware that devcon is a thing, but it doesn't look like it's meant to be redistributed (and for the latest version, we'd have to install WDK on end-users machines, something that's serious overkill for this one fix we need to do).

Is anyone away of anything else that allows us to programmatically modify which driver a device uses in windows? I've already pinged the device/driver manufacturer over this, but haven't heard back form them.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions require Administrator privileges.

Devcon is part of the Windows Driver Kit, Visual Studio, or the
Windows SDK for desktop apps.
To avoid downloading these heavy products, see in Github the project of
[DevCon-Installer](https://github.com/Drawbackz/DevCon-Installer),
where Devcon was recompiled from source.

Another possible utility is
[PnPUtil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil),
which is part of Windows and so does not require installation.

Answer (score 0):

With a Powershell-script you should be able to change device drivers.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\mydrivers\" -Recurse -Filter "*.inf" | 
ForEach-Object { PNPUtil.exe /add-driver $_.FullName /install }
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/add-windowsdriver?view=win10-ps

I hope it'll be some hint for you